# Handle text error in log pipeline Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following pipeline:

```
       pipeline {
    agent {
        label labelValue
    }

    stages {
        stage("Git") {
            steps {
                script {
                    git branch: "develop",
                            credentialsId: "xxx",
                            url: "https://"
                }
            }
        }

        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                withMaven(jdk: 'openjdk-12_linux') {
                    sh 'mvn clean compile assembly:single'
                }
            }
        }        

        stage("Run") {
            steps {
                withMaven(jdk: 'openjdk-12_linux', maven: 'Maven 3.6.3' {
                    sh 'java -jar SomethingName.jar ${par1} ${par2} ${par3} ${BUILD_URL}'
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

When I run a jar with an autotest, then in case of an error, there is a text "FAIL" in the logs, and in case of success there is a text "SUCCESS". how to use TextFinder to catch the desired text ("FAIL") and, in case of an error, "dump" the job. Otherwise, all jobs are green and successful

Comment: I'd avoid matching certain phrases in the log to determine the success of a stage since it's prone to false positives because something else might log that. Instead, I'd advise to use the exit code of the program to determine the success of the stage. If you think that's not possible, try to wrap it in a bash script and add some more intelligent logic for estimating the success, and then throw the corresponding exit status. After that, use the "post" with "success" and "failure" to execute follow-up actions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just trying to see if your log contain a certain string, you can have a `post` step;

```
post {
  always {
    if (currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(1000).contains("SUCCESS")){
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

where `1000` is the number of lines in the log to read. Regardless of the job result, you will reach this block and the if condition will get checked.

But like the comment above mentions, this is not a great way to determine if your stage failed or passed and proper exit codes are `success` or `failure` blocks to handle those errors are the best way to handle this.

Comment: thank you, it worked for me if I wrap your solution in a function(`def func() {...}`)